# get itemscontrol reference  from item 

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

i need to drag items between several itemcontrols , each are bound to it's own collection 
when i drag an item i need to know which itemscontrol it was originally dragged from .

the draggable item template :

```
  <DataTemplate>
        <Ellipse MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown" ></Ellipse>
  </DataTemplate>
```

the itemscontrols :

```
  <ItemsControl Name="Pipe23" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pipes[23].Checkers}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PipeDataItem}"/>
  <ItemsControl Name="Pipe22" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pipes[22].Checkers}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PipeDataItem}"/>
  <ItemsControl Name="Pipe21" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pipes[21].Checkers}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PipeDataItem}"/>
  <ItemsControl Name="Pipe20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pipes[20].Checkers}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PipeDataItem}"/>
```

when dragging an item on the MouseDown event i can reference the item being dragged but i also need 
to reference the itemscontrol it was dragged from : how can this be done ?

```
    private void Ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)sender;
        Checker checker = (Checker)ellipse.DataContext;
        //  how do i reference the itemsconrtol containing the current ellipse (item)    
    }
```

Comment: Rachel's blog holds a great solution, VisualTree helpers
http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would navigate up the [VisualTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx#two_trees) until I find an `ItemsControl` object, and that would be the parent.

I have some [VisualTree helpers](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) posted on my blog that does this, and I could use them like this to find the parent `ItemsControl`:

```
private void Ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)sender;
    Checker checker = (Checker)ellipse.DataContext;

    ItemsControl parent = VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<ItemsControl>(ellipse); 
}
```

Comment: just one thing :

VisualTreeHelper does not have FindAncestor 
i used 
VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(ellipse);  
which returns something called a ContentPresenter

Comment: @eranotzer Add an `s` to the end of that. I called it `VisualTreeHelpers` before I realized there was already a class called `VisualTreeHelper`. You could also rename the class to something else.

Comment: i was unable to find such a class 
are you sure it's not 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx

Comment: @eranotzer To use `VisualTreeHelpers.FindAncestor<T>` you need to add the code found in my blog article to your project (or create your own). It's a custom class with some custom methods which makes navigating the Visual Tree easier.

Comment: there must be a built in way of doing this
thanks ill check it out

Comment: @eranotzer The `VisualTreeHelper` object is the built-in way of navigating the VisualTree, however I found myself writing the code to navigate the VisualTree so often that I just built a helper class containing the most commonly used functions so I could use a single line of code to navigate the VisualTree. All the code is posted on my blog, so feel free to just copy/paste it and use what you need if you prefer.

Comment: i saw your code , seems like a great tool , i'm gonna use it
thanks for all your help.

Comment: if you don't mind having a look iv'e got a big problem with 
something of interest 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646674/wpf-unable-to-drag-drop-items-between-bound-itemscontrols