# Unable to drag drop items between bound itemscontrols

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, itemscontrol

iv'e  got several bound itemscontrols which all play the role of of drop target 
i need to be able to drag drop items between these items controls .

the problem is that the items control's are not recognized as drop targets by the drag drop framework

**The ItemsControl Panel :**

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="TopPipePanelTemplate">
            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

**The DataTemplate :**

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PipeDataItem" >
        <Ellipse Width="45" Height="45" Fill="{Binding IsMine,Converter={StaticResource MyCheckerOwnerToColorConverter}}"></Ellipse>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**The ItemsControl Style :**

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}" x:Key="ItemsControlStyle">
          <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PipeDataItem}"></Setter>
          <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"></Setter>                                      
          <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="ItemsControlDropTarget"></EventSetter> 
          <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ItemsControl_MouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>      
    </Style>
```

** for this example lets take 2 of The ItemsControls :**

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pipes[23].Checkers}" Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlStyle}"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pipes[22].Checkers}" Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlStyle}"/>
```

when regularly displayed :

[image]

the empty ( Left ) one is not recognized as a drop target although it as AllowDrop set to True and 
handles the Drop event ( as do all the itemscontrols in this screen , look at ItemsControl Style above )

now when i color the itemscontrol panel it s suddenly is recognized   :

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="TopPipePanelTemplate">
            <StackPanel Background="AliceBlue"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

[image]

as if now it takes up the entire cell which it occupies .. 
iv'e tried setting the panel to  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" but this also had no affect

i'm trying to understand why my itemcontrols are not recognized as drop enabled ,
even though i expect that they take up that space , in addition the itemscontrol with the ellipses 
is only recognized until the height of the ellipses that occupie it's content .

any ideas ?

just to clarify  what i mean by Recognized as drop target is when you drag the ellipse you are able 
to drop it on top of the itemscontrol .

**for now iv'e just set the background as Transparent**

Comment: the solution was setting a transparent background so that the stackpanel stretches to fit the entire cell .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default background color of a panel doesn't exist, which means hit tests pass through it. To get it to register hit tests, such as mouse over events, you need to give it a background color. Usually I just use `White`, although you said `Transparent` also works and would be a better choice.

In addition, `StackPanels` will usually only take up the space they need. You might be better off using a Panel that stretches to fill all available space, such as a `DockPanel` with `LastChildFill="False"`, and set `DockPanel.Dock="Top"` on your items

Comment: iv'e actually now did give it a value if transparent for the background
and it does work :)
i didn't know that stackpanels took  only the space they require 
i'll check how i could use a dockpanel instead , 
but as i said iv'e already found a work around for this 
thanks for all your help , now iv'e got a another problem though 
if you don't mind taking a look .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647341/update-ui-when-adding-to-observable-collection#comment12249136_9647341

Comment: @eranotzer Hrrrm so perhaps the default background is `Null` then, not `Transparent`. I remember I ran into this issue a while back, and I just remember I had to set a background color on the panel to get it to register for mouse events.