# Update UI when adding to observable collection

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, observablecollection

iv'e got 2 itemscontrols bound to 2 observable collections

**my ItemsControls :**

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="4"  Name="Pipe19"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pipes[19].Checkers}" Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlStyle}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource TopPipePanelTemplate}" />
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="5"  Name="Pipe18"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pipes[18].Checkers}" Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlStyle}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource TopPipePanelTemplate}" />
```

**their definitions through style :**

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}" x:Key="ItemsControlStyle">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PipeDataItem}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"></Setter>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ItemsControl_MouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
         <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="ItemsControl_Drop"></EventSetter>
   </Style>
```

both are considered drop targets , they contain ellipse items which i need to drag from one to the other . the problem is the  Add  part of the operation doesn't get rendered to the UI .

**Visual Helper :**

[image]

when drag drop as ellipse from the right one to the left :

**this is the code which grabs the ellipse and saves the source control**

```
    private void ItemsControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsControl control = (ItemsControl)sender;
        UIElement element = control.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(control)) as UIElement;

        if (element != null)
        {
            Ellipse ellipse = element as Ellipse;
            DragSource = control;
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(ellipse, ellipse, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
```

**this is the code where the ellipse is dropped onto it's target :**

```
    private void ItemsControl_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsControl target = (ItemsControl)sender;
        Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Ellipse));
        ((ObservableCollection<Checker>)DragSource.ItemsSource).Remove(ellipse.DataContext as Checker); 
        ((ObservableCollection<Checker>)target.ItemsSource).Add(ellipse.DataContext as Checker); 
    }
```

the Checkers collections are described as follows : (Take notice that they are the itemscontrols ItemsSource :

```
public class Pipe  
{    
    private ObservableCollection<Checker> checkers;
    public ObservableCollection<Checker> Checkers
    {
        get 
        {
            if (checkers == null)
                checkers = new ObservableCollection<Checker>();
            return checkers; 
        }            
    }        
}
```

after the ItemsControl_Drop event the result is that only the remove updated the UI but the add on the target add not (i would expect that a new item would appear on the left one which i called Add on it's itemsource :

**Another Visual Aid :**

[image]

any ideas ?

Comment: What might be going on is the Add does not yet have a collection.
Please try re factoring to:


    public class Pipe  
    {    
        private ObservableCollection<Checker> checkers = new ObservableCollection<Checker>();
        public ObservableCollection<Checker> Checkers
        { get { return checkers; }            
    }

Put a debug before and after the add to get a count. 

And try the Add before the remove.

Comment: iv'e tried creating them before setting the binding 
but still it does not work. 
@Blam  iv'e noticed that when i call Add 
it does not go into the checkers collection where i put my breakpoint 
that's kinda odd , as if it now does not recognize the collection it is bound to .. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that your adding to the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl instead of directly to the Pipes[#].Checkers.
I notice that the remove method is a remove from DragSource.ItemsSource.
You probably have a DragTargetControl which ItemsSource you should add to, which will update the Binding.
In the way your doing it you might be undoing the Binding if you cast the Binded ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection.

Comment: o'k i didn't know i could undo the binding 
you mean 
((ObservableCollection<Checker>)target.ItemsSource).Add(ellipse.DataContext as Checker);

treats it as if it's a new ItemsSource ?

Comment: You are not really touching your binding. However you are not really updating the source to which the binding points either. The binding references to the original object. You might wanna update the collection through the original model.

Comment: And I would not recommend accessing properties through Pipes[19].Checkers. Rather set the DataContext of the control to {Binding Path=Pipes[19]} and the ItemsSource to {Binding Path=Checkers}

Comment: i'll try that out ,though i don't really understand why this isn't 
my binding ..

Comment: well it wasn't that it turns out i should of added before removing 
the ellipse  it referred to the ellipse as a Disconnected item ..

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what is going on.  I bet Pipes[] is not an ObservableCollection.  Try it with Pipe1 and Pipe2.  Remove from Pipe1 and add to Pipe2.

Comment: they don't need to be 
sorry iv'e already solved this  i should of posted my answer

Comment: the only problem was that apparently removing the ellipse from the itemscontrol before adding it to the other , made the ellipse be 
as referred by the debugger as a disconnected item ..
i guess it loses it's reference somehow in the wpf framework

Comment: Read the last sentence of my first comment.  "And try the Add before the remove."

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the ui element some how loses it's reference if you remove it 
from one observable collection before adding it to another ,

so i added the ellipse to the target and then removed it from the source .

```
    private void ItemsControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsControl control = (ItemsControl)sender;
        UIElement element = control.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(control)) as UIElement;

        if (element != null && (element is Ellipse))
        {
            Ellipse ellipse = element as Ellipse;
            DragSource = control;
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(ellipse, ellipse, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    private void ItemsControl_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsControl target = (ItemsControl)sender;
        Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Ellipse));
        ObservableCollection<Checker> collection = target.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Checker>;
        Checker checker = ellipse.DataContext as Checker;
        collection.Add(checker);
        ((ObservableCollection<Checker>)DragSource.ItemsSource).Remove(ellipse.DataContext as Checker);

    }
```